# D3 to match this QGIS projection?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, d3

I have a map of Finland in QGIS, which says CRS = ETRS89 / ETRS-TM35 (Authority ID = EPSG:3047).

I'm trying to show the map with D3, and  can't quite match the borders/projection. The black one is the D3 output and the blue one is from QGIS:

[image: Two projections]

I played around with some projections in D3 and the closest seemed to be this:

```
var projection = d3.geo.transverseMercator().scale(1).translate([0,0]).rotate([1, 0, -45]);
```

(I am scaling and translating it more before outputing. Also I used ogr2ogr to create the geojson. The data files are [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33485810/qgis-d3-data.7z).)

ogr2ogr command used:

```
 ogr2ogr -f 'GeoJSON' -s_srs kunnat.prj -t_srs 'EPSG:4326'  kunnat.geojson kunnat.shp
```

Is there a way to achieve a perfect match to that of QGIS picture?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`EPSG:3047` is UTM Zone 35, which has its central meridian at 27°E. To get this projection using `d3`, you need to use

```
 d3.geo.transverseMercator().rotate([-27,0,0])
```

(or `d3.geo.transverseMercator().rotate([-27,-65,0])` if you also want to use the projection to center on your area of interest).

Here's the overlay of the QGIS and `d3` output:

[image]

Comment: Very nice, thank you! I'm not totally sure if I could have arrived at that answer, even if I had taken it into account that UTM Zone 35 is at 27°E. But then again, this is all new to new so, a lot of new things to learn. 


transverseMercator I also picked a bit randomly, but it seemed to work better than mercator which I also tried. Wonder why QGIS doesn't say it's using transverseMercator, which it seems to be using.

Comment: @ile: You're welcome! "UTM" stands for ["Universal Transverse Mercator"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system).

Comment: Got it done. 

One thing that escapes me is how I can arrive at the right scale or translate values - but I get the feeling I'm asking too many newbie questions. Any links/faqs on the issue?